# Route get by _id queries in Elasticsearch to improve performance?

Tags: performance, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I have an Elasticsearch index with hundreds of millions of documents that is used mostly for the "get by id" queries.

I consider adding a route to documents when indexing. The route will be a random number from 0 to 9.

Later this route will be in an URL with the document id, it that will be used to get the document. Currently I have only document ids in the [URLs](https://tarta.ai/j/xFrlQXoB5JkM4hVkY9eB-uipath-platform-architect-in-reston-virginia) but plan to add routes as well. The new URL will look like this https://tarta.ai/ j/ [route] /[doc id].

I'm wondering will it decrease the time needed to find a document in the index? My suggestion is that Elasticsearch in this case won't look for a document in all the shards but instead will look only in the shards with this particular route.

---

Some elasticsearch specs:

- index size is 110gb.
- the number of docs is 36m but we're adding hundreds of thousands every day.
- 5 shards.
- 16GB RAM and 2 core vm with a 1t SSD.

Answer (score 1):

Routing is especially useful when searching (i.e. `POST index/_search`), because instead of searching all the shards of an index, ES will only search the single shard to which the routing value resolves to.

If you specify a `routing` value when indexing a document, you MUST specify the same routing value when GETting that document, there's no alternative.

```
# index with routing
PUT index/_doc/1?routing=123

# returns the document
GET index/_doc/1?routing=123

# returns nothing
GET index/_doc/1
```

If you don't specify any routing value when indexing a document, ES will use the ID as the routing value and store the document on the shard to which that routing value resolves to. So when GETting such a document without any routing value, ES will know to use the ID as the routing value, which is why you don't have to specify it (although you could).

```
# index without routing
PUT index/_doc/1

# returns the document
GET index/_doc/1

# returns the document as well
GET index/_doc/1?routing=1
```

What that means is that for GET operations, routing or no routing makes no difference, it's mainly for search that routing has an added value.

When using routing, another thing you need to make sure is that your IDs should be "well-balanced" so that their hash can resolve to any shard with a similar probability. If that's not the case, you run the risk of creating hot-spots in your index, i.e. some shards can be bigger than others.